# nodejs + mysql + individual user

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a client which will send the id ( ex. email ) to nodejs program on server. Email will actually be of the logged-in user.

And nodejs program should keep updating a particular div on client side(say pushing data every 3 seconds) with relevant data for that email address.

Same should be done on multiple machines, wherein every machine has separate person logged-in via email. Something like what happens on gmail.

I have built it as follows, but when i open it from multiple clients, the value of latest client(email) overwrites the value of previous ones and all client show data for latest email only.

### Code is as shown below for both server and client.

### server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray = [],
    profile_id,
    last_count = 0, //this variable is to check previous count value
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '', //put your own mysql pwd
        database: 'test', //put your database name
        port: 3306
    }),
    POLLING_INTERVAL = 1000,
    pollingTimer;

// If there is an error connecting to the database
connection.connect(function(err) {
    // connected! (unless `err` is set)
    console.log(err);
});
console.log('DB connected');
// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);

// on server started we can load our client.html page
function handler(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/indexnew.html', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading client.html');
        }
        console.log('File loaded');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

/*
 * HERE IT IS THE COOL PART
 * This function loops on itself since there are sockets connected 
 * to the page. Upon Update it only emits the notification if 
 * the value has changed.
 * Polling the database after a constant interval
 */

var pollingLoop = function() {
    sql = "SELECT count(*) as c FROM activity_log WHERE notified=0 and (profile_id = '" + profile_id + "')";
    console.log(sql);
    // Doing the database query
    var query = connection.query(sql),
        users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

    // setting the query listeners
    query
        .on('error', function(err) {
            // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
            console.log(err);
            updateSockets(err);
        })
        .on('result', function(count) {
            // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
            users.push(count);
            // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
            if (connectionsArray.length) {
                pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
                updateSockets({
                    users: users,
                    count: count.c
                });
            }
        })
};

// creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Connected');
    //This variable is passed via the client at the time of socket //connection, see "io.connect(..." line in client.html
    profile_id = socket.handshake.query.profile_id;
    console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
    // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
    if (!connectionsArray.length) {
        pollingLoop();
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
        console.log('socket = ' + socketIndex + ' disconnected');
        if (socketIndex >= 0) {
            connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
        }
    });

    console.log('A new socket is connected!');
    connectionsArray.push(socket);

});

var updateSockets = function(data) {
    if (last_count != data.count) {
        // adding the time of the last update
        data.time = new Date();
        // sending new data to all the sockets connected
        connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
            tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
        });
    }
    last_count = data.count;
};
```

**indexnew.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Push notification long polling server streaming on a MySQL db</title>
    <style>
        dd,
        dt {
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            clear: both;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }

        dt {
            background: #ddd;
        }

        time {
            color: gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <time></time>
    <div id="container">Loading ...</div>
    <script src="socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var rno = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        // create a new websocket
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/?profile_id=' + rno);
        // on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
        socket.on('notification', function(data) {
            var usersList = "<dl>";
            $.each(data.users, function(index, count) {
                usersList += "<dt>" + count.c + "</dt>\n";
            });

            usersList += "</dl>";
            $('#container').html(usersList);

            $('time').html('Last Update:' + data.time);
            $('sql').html('Last Update:' + data.sql);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your pollingLoop function and query is structured you will only ever retrieve the last profile_id. Here is why:
The profile_id variable is a global variable, existing on the server thread. The way you've programmed it so far, it seems that you want your pollingLoop to handle all of your sockets at once, but then inside the pollingLoop, you use the global variable profile_id to pull down the information from the database. Every time a new user connects the 'connected' event fires, which updates the profile_id to that user.

- Here are some options for what you can do to solve for this:
  Construct your query to pull all the profile_id's that are connected,
  and build your update_sockets to only send the count for each
  profile_id to the appropriate socket.
- You can use "group by" to help
  with your counts. You could make the pollingLoop run for each
  connected user individually. You could keep your query as it is.

Either way you will have to fix your profile_id, because it doesn't make sense to have it contain a single user's unique id in a global setting. If you truly want the profile_id to be a session-based unique ID, doing a random number is a bit dangerous. I would suggest using the socket.id that socket.io exposes for each socket. This way you don't have to worry about it being unique, you don't have to pass it along, and you don't have to store it yourself. The socket.id will be available to you in the connectionsArray since that contains all your sockets. So in the pollingLoop you can loop over the ID's to construct your query, and in the updateSockets you can pair the results back to the socket that needs to receive the data particular to that user.

One more note about a comment in your connection event:
// starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
This comment is inaccurate, I think it should say:
// starting the loop only if there are no other users connected yet

I hope that helps you!